# Run a flow when document approval status = "Pending"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, approval-process

We have the following SharePoint document library:

[image: image.png]

Now we want to run a flow only when the user Publish the document (when its status is changed from Draft to Pending), so I tried this trigger condition:

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{_ModerationStatus}'],2)
```

[image]

But the flow will never get executed. Any advice?

Comment: check the field name '_ModerationStatus' , is the internal name _ModerationStatus ? try it using _ModerationStatus0  in the trigger condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When a file is created or modified in a folder" trigger does not return Approval Status column value in `triggerOutputs`.

Instead use "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" trigger.

Then use trigger condition like:

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{ModerationStatus}'],'Pending')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this flow:
[image: flow]

====================
If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: User already using SharePoint default content approval on document library